# about indexes created on primary keys referenced as foreign keys in a different table (SQLite3)

Tags: database, database-design, sqlite, indexing, foreign-keys

Scenario for my database design is as follows: people visit matchmakers who network with each other and propose matches. For example, person A visits matchmaker X, and person B visits matchmaker Y, where A not equals B and no constraint on X, Y i.e. they can be the same or different.

```
create table matchmaker ( id TEXT primary key, address TEXT );

create table people ( id TEXT primary key, name TEXT, gender TEXT, matchmaker_id TEXT,
    foreign key(matchmaker_id) references matchmaker(id));

create table married_couples ( id1 TEXT, id2 TEXT,
    foreign key (id1) references people(id), 
    foreign key (id2) reference people(id));
```

Then, for faster database access:

```
create index matchmaker_index on matchmaker(id);
create index people_index on people(id);
```

My question is based on the following query to generate tuples of matchmaker pairs with people they've paired.

```
select a.id, b.id, e.id1, e.id2
from matchmaker as a, matchmaker as b, 
people as c, people as d, 
married_couples as e
where e.id1 = c.id and c.id = a.id and 
e.id2 = d.id and d.id = b.id;
```

For the query above, will the two matchmaker_index and people_index suffice or, 
is there a need for two more (other) indexes as below?

```
create index matchmaker_people_index on people(id, matchmaker_id);
create index married_couples_index on married_couples(id1, id2);
```

additional info:

1) matchmaker has 20074 unique entries;

2) people has 20494819 unique entries;

3) married_couples ?? (i don't have this information yet, but it's going to be big)

Also, it's possible that married_couples will have duplicate entries. So, 
after creating the relevant indexes, will run query to delete duplicates as below:

```
delete from married_couples 
where rowid not in ( select min(rowid)
    from married_couples
    group by id1, id2);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite generates indexes automatically for columns declared `primary key` or `unique`.  [FAQ, see question 7](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html). So these two indexes

```
create index matchmaker_index on matchmaker(id);
create index people_index on people(id);
```

are duplicates. Drop them.

This index

```
create index matchmaker_people_index on people(id, matchmaker_id);
```

might help.

> Also, it's possible that married_couples will have duplicate entries.

Remove that possibility. Add a primary key *and* a CHECK constraint.

```
create table married_couples ( 
  id1 TEXT, id2 TEXT,
    foreign key (id1) references people(id), 
    foreign key (id2) references people(id),
    primary key (id1, id2),
    check (id1 < id2)
);
```

The primary key provides an index, too.

When you're talking about marriages, a marriage between Mike and Mindy is a duplicate of a marriage between Mindy and Mike. The CHECK constraint prevents that kind of subtle duplication. It also prevents people from marrying themselves.

I'm not sure what you might want to do about the woman who married the Eiffel Tower.

You can simplify the original query quite a lot. Learning ANSI joins is a good idea.

```
select id1, id2, c.matchmaker_id m_id1, d.matchmaker_id m_id2
from married_couples a
inner join people c
  on c.id = a.id1
inner join people d
  on d.id = a.id1;
```

Comment: You did not mention [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), which shows that the additional index does not help.